# Hive: Joining tables with different scenarios

Tags: hadoop, hql, hive, hiveql

I have a question on joining tables in a different scenario. Please find the sample tables below.

Capacity of expected table row 3-5 should be repeated as table 2 does not have those fields.

could anyone please help to get expected table?

## Table 1:

No  ProjectID   Capacity

1   514 4

2   418 10

3   418 30

4   401 40

5   502 41

## Table2:

NO  ProjectID   Capacity1   Capacity2

1   514 4   10

2   418 10  20

## Expected Table:

NO  ProjectID   Capacity1   Capacity2

1   514 4   10

2   418 10  20

3   418 30  30

4   401 40  40

5   502 41  41

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Do left outer join

2.For the values not matching take them from table 1 with if condition.

```
   select t1.no,t1.projectid,t1.capacity1,if(t2.capacity2 is null,t1.capacity,t2.capacity)
    from table1 t1 left outer join table2 t2 on t1.no=t2.no
```

I think above query meets your requirement let me know if need any more help.

Comment: It works! Looks like i should improve my knowledge on these areas. Thanks  a lot for your quick help!

Comment: I am glad I can help someone on Hive